# keyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I was setting up prepackaged WSO2 identity server with WSO2 API Manager.Also was configuring the domain urls.
Now while starting WSO2 API Manager , below error is printed in the logs

```
[2017-05-12 05:37:35,237]  INFO - CarbonEventManagementService Starting polling event receivers
[2017-05-12 05:37:55,848]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-05-12 05:37:55,850]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-05-12 05:38:01,861]  WARN - FileSystemPreferences Could not lock System prefs. Unix error code 32693.
[2017-05-12 05:38:01,861]  WARN - FileSystemPreferences Couldn't flush system prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.
[2017-05-12 05:38:10,877]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-05-12 05:38:10,878]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-05-12 05:38:25,940]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2017-05-12 05:38:25,940]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
```

Can anyone tell me what could have i done wrong..May be i did some configuration wrong.Where should i check to find the problem?
Can it be because of SSL issues? I have not yet set up SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this seems to be from SSL handshake failure specially since you have used hostnames. The default certificates that come with WSO2 Servers are created for localhost.

You can try creating self-signed certificates for APIM and IS hostnames. Then export the public certs of APIM to trust-store.jks of IS and vice versa. This should resolve the SSL handshake failure.

So what happens is when APIM boots up it makes an HTTP call to a web app in Key Manager (throttle data at KM_URL/throttle/data/v1/keyTemplates). APIM decides the URL of the KM from the  URL configured in the api-manager.xml

You are seeing the error,

```
WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. Retrying after 15 seconds...
```

because the APIM cannot make this HTTP call retrieve throttle data from KM.